# "unable to get password" when trying to unzip password-protected archive

Tags: password, zip

In Total Commander in Windows I created a password-protected zip-archive.
I can't unzip files from it in Ubuntu 17.10 (neither in Files nor in Krusader). 
Then I extracted all files in Windows, started Ubuntu and packed them all in a new password-protected archive (in Krusader I think). These files can be extracted using the new password in the Ubuntu File Manager (Files), but they cannot be extracted in Krusader. So I guess I am reporting 2 problems...
Somewhere in the middle of this I followed an advice telling me to use the command 'sudo apt-get install p7zip' in the terminal. I don't know if that helped or worsened things... :-)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My questions: 1. Why can't I unzip files that were password protected in Windows? 2. Why can't I unzip the new archive in Krusader?

Answer (score 0):

p7zip did not worsen thing! I your desktop, you want to find the p7zip client and have it accept all versions. It does not do so by default. I am sure it will work for you then. It has never failed me once I set if for all versions.

Comment: How do I "find the p7zip client and have it accept all versions"?

Comment: Try this link: https://omghowto.com/how-to-install-7zip-in-ubuntu-to-open-7z-zip-files.html

Comment: OK. Now I have done the "sudo apt-get install p7zip-full" command in Terminal, but I still can't unzip password protected files in Krusader even though they can be unzipped in Files. I still get the "Access denied" - “unable to get password” error.