# How to type anything in Location Toolbar of Krusader

Tags: mtp, krusader

When I plug-in my Android phone by USB, it gets mounted as 
"mtp://....." and I can see my photos in 'Files' (Nautilus), but I would like to see them in Krusader. So I found a post telling me to type "mtp:" into the Location Toolbar of Krusader and according to the manual (Krusader.pdf) you CAN type an address:

"The user can enter a desired path by clicking on it."

But that doesn't work in Krusader on my Ubuntu 17.10!
What is wrong?

PS: This is not the only problem I have with Krusader - the other problems are described here:

[Krusader window too wide - can't be changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019113/krusader-window-too-wide-cant-be-changed)

["unable to get password" when trying to unzip password-protected archive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019099/unable-to-get-password-when-trying-to-unzip-password-protected-archive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by forcing Krusader to create a new configuration file by renaming the file "~/.config/krusaderrc". See [Krusader window too wide - can't be changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019113/krusader-window-too-wide-cant-be-changed)